# Going back one iteration in foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, .net, collections, foreach, iteration

I have a `foreach` loop that iterates different levels of a `treeView` in C# that its simplified version looks like this:

```
foreach (TreeNode childNode in currentNode.Nodes)
{
    if (!someCondition)
    {
        currentNode.Remove();                    
    }
}
```

but the problem is that when a node (for example from a list of node1, node2, node3 and node4) is removed the list becomes shorter and the `foreach` loop skips one iteration (for example, say if node2 was to be removed the list becomes node1, node3 and node4 and the next node that the `foreach` loop considers will be node4 instead of node3). This is because the framework is storing these nodes in an array/list so I would like to know if it is possible to make a `foreach` loop go back one iteration when I want to remove a node from the tree.

I'm pretty new in .NET framework so your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, note that if you call `currentNode.Remove()`, it is entirely legal for your iterator to break completely: you are not guaranteed to be able to iterate a sequence that changes while you are iterating it. Why not perform the removals *after* you have figured out what you want to remove?

Comment: You must not modifying a collection while iterate throught, this will crash your app

Comment: Why don't you change foreach to for loop? It's absolutly legal to remove items within for-loop.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Although it's much easier if you iterate the for-loop backwards :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***for loop*** here:

```
// Pay attention to reversed order:
// each currentNode.Remove() changes currentNode.Nodes.Count 
for (int i = currentNode.Nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)  {
  TreeNode childNode = currentNode.Nodes[i];

  if (!someCondition) {
    currentNode.Remove();                    
  }
}
```

Comment: This works well, I have used an approach like that myself in the past, however I would consider it as bad practice.

Comment: @Codor: Yes, the Linq solution is elegant one, but if you have an elaborated for-each loop (as the question suggested) it's often easier to convert it to for loop.

Comment: I'm trying to rebuild the tree with some nodes removed so I guess this approach will place the nodes in wrong order. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Mark The code you showed is only removing nodes, not adding nodes, so the order they are removed shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Mark: No shouldn't rearrange the tree; it just changes the order in which nodes/branches removing

Answer (score 5):

The desired result can perhaps be achieved using Linq by setting

```
currentNode.Nodes = currentNode.Nodes.Where( n => SomeCondition( n ) ).ToList();
```

or something similar, so no explicit iteration is necessary. A less elegant solution is using an explicit `for`-loop running backwards, so that the loop index cannot become invalid. However I would consider this bad practice when a more structural approach is available.

Comment: I know almost nothing about Linq so if my condition is this currentNode.Nodes.Count == 0 && !currentNode.Text.Contains(this.txtFilter.Text), how will this look like?

Comment: Where( n => n.Nodes.Count==0 && !n.Text.Contains(this.txtFilter.Text) )

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible because the iterations of a `foreach` loop aren't "indexed" in a strict sense.
A `for` loop is, however, indexed because you provide it with a counting mechanism yourself. There you can change your counter.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's not a great idea to modify the collection that you are iterating through within a foreach. You should consider using a for loop instead and manually keep track of the current index.

Comment: well it's always a bad idea, because you can't

Comment: @Jonesy No, that's not true.  Some iterators specifically check for modifications to the underlying collection and throw.  Some just don't, and will happily continue on while skipping items, showing items twice, spitting out garbage, or any number of other possibly undefined options.

Comment: That's interesting.  What type could I modify in a `foreach` without a thrown error?

Comment: @Jonesy Well, according to the OP's question, TreeNode.Nodes does not check for this in its iterator, as as per his question, removing items results in skipped items, not an exception, so not only are such collections theoretically possible, but *this is one of them*.  You have to go out of your way to have an iterator support this.  The widely used general purpose collections obviously took the time to do this (although you could write your own iterators for them that don't) but that's not to say every iterator does.